# Printing MongoDB Collection Data - GoLang, results not as expected

Tags: mongodb, go

I have mongoDB in a Docker container, I can connect to and update the DB just fine, I can see the results in Compass. However when it comes to grabbing a collection and printing the results they don't print as I expect them too.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
db := client.Database("maccaption")
collection := client.Database("maccaption").Collection("JobBacklog")
res, err := collection.InsertOne(context.Background(), bson.M{"hello": "world"})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
result := struct {
    Foo string
    Bar string
}{}
filter := bson.D{{"hello", "world"}}
err = collection.FindOne(context.Background(), filter).Decode(&result)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println("Results", result)
```

I'm using the official mongo-go-driver. and following the examples here https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo

I know the DB is connected, I can see the update when I add to the DB and then it shows up in Compass when I run the code, but the `collection.FindOne` returns `Results {0}` when I expect it to return `hello: world`.

Can anyone help me with this? 
Thanks!

Comment: You've inserted a document with a field `hello` with value `"world"`. You're then trying to unpack that document into a struct with fields `Foo` and `Bar`. Neither of those are named `Hello` and neither has a `bson` tag, so your result is exactly what I would expect.

Comment: Try `result := struct{ Hello string }` instead and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the code with your suggestion and it works, now the results are `&{ObjectID("5c2e500421b2820262a9fee6")}`  any suggestions how to get the actual data stored instead of just the ID?

Comment: Scratch that - typo on my part. Worked great. Thank you!

Comment: Reposted as answer for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've inserted a document with a field hello with value "world". You're then trying to unpack that document into a struct with fields Foo and Bar. Neither of those are named Hello and neither has a bson tag, so there is nowhere it *should* unmarshal your `hello` field to. If you define instead:

```
result := struct{
    Hello string
}
```

It should unmarshal as desired.